# Proper use of parameters

Tags: function, powershell

What is a good practice to handle parameters, when do I choose what option?

Example: usually I write functions like this:

```
function Do-Something ($variable1, $variable2, $variable3....) 
    { Do Stuff }
```

Now apparently this is also an option:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=0,
        Mandatory=$True,
        ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    [string]$userName,
    ...
)
```

I can, however, not find out why to use the second, or what the advantages really are to use this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the second `Param()` block allows you to do a lot of advanced param validation.

if I need to write a short function with minimal input validation i'll use something like this:

```
Function Test-Port ([string]$Server,[uint16]$Port=80,[uint16]$Timeout = 3000) {
    #code here
}
```

but if I need to write something with advanced checking like this:

```
function Get-SiteCert{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = "Return")]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [string]$Server,
        [Parameter(Position=1)]
        [uint16]$Port=443,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="RawObj")]
        [switch]$Raw,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, ParameterSetName="Export")]
        [switch]$Export,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="Export")]
        [string]$Path,
        [uint16]$Timeout=3000
    )
    #code here
}
```

I'm definitely not fitting it all into the top bar, even though they're similar scripts, the second one 'does' a lot more. it's really just a case by case basis.

you can check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1) for examples of what you can do with the expansive parameters, but if you don't need these feel free to keep using whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

As @ConnorLSW wrote in the above answer, validation is one of the biggest benefits. With the `Param` block you're able to use `Validate` attributes, like:

```
Function Foo
{
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [ValidateSet("Tom","Dick","Jane")]
    [String]
    $Name
,
    [ValidateRange(21,65)]
    [Int]
    $Age
,
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Container'})]
    [string]
    $Path
)
Process
{
    write-host "New-Foo"
}
```

}

You are also able to define different parameter sets, if your function should support different parameter combination. Additionally you'll also get "out-of-box" documentation via `Get-Help` if you are the `Mandatory` and `Positional` properties of the `Parameter` attribute. E.g.:

```
 get-help Foo -Detailed

 NAME
   Foo

 SYNTAX
Foo [-Name] {Tom | Dick | Jane} [[-Age] <int>] [-Path <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]


PARAMETERS
-Age <int>

-Name <string>

-Path <string>

<CommonParameters>
    This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
    ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
    OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see 
    about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216). 


ALIASES
   None

REMARKS
   None
```

Based on the out brackets of the `Age` parameter you'll that it is an optional parameter. So its all about description, validation and documentation.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Clarified quite a bit. Will be needing the second block for my new script.